# PostgreSQL Query to get pivot result

Tags: postgresql

I have a log table look like this

```
rpt_id | shipping_id | shop_id | status | create_time
-------------------------------------------------------------
1      | 1           | 600     | 1      | 2013-12-01 01:06:50
2      | 1           | 600     | 0      | 2013-12-01 01:06:55
3      | 1           | 600     | 1      | 2013-12-02 10:00:30
4      | 2           | 600     | 1      | 2013-12-02 10:00:30
5      | 1           | 601     | 1      | 2013-12-02 11:20:10
6      | 2           | 601     | 1      | 2013-12-02 11:20:10
7      | 1           | 601     | 0      | 2013-12-03 09:10:10
8      | 3           | 602     | 1      | 2013-12-03 13:15:58
```

And I want to use single query to make it look like this

```
shipping_id | total_activate | total_deactivate
-----------------------------------------------
1           | 2              | 2
2           | 2              | 0
3           | 1              | 0
```

How should I query this?

**Note**:

- Status = 1 = Activate
- Status = 0 = Deactivate
- Count total activate / deactivate rule: look at log table above. rpt_id 1 & 3, it has same shop_id, shipping_id and status. It should only count as one. See the result table. Shipping id 1 is only activated by 2 shops, they are shop_id 600 and 601.

Can you guys advice me how to make the query? thanks for the help:D

Comment: No time to answer right now, but search for "crosstab"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select shipping_id,
       sum(case when status=1 then 1 else 0 end) as total_activate,
       sum(case when status=0 then 1 else 0 end) as total_deactivate
from (select distinct shipping_id, 
                      shop_id, 
                      status
        from test) a
group by shipping_id
order by shipping_id
```

See it here at fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f15fd/4

I did not put the date on the query as it is not important for the result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes thanks... I also figured it out already, you can do it this way too.... thx

```
SELECT 
    shipping_id, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN shop_id END) AS total_activate, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN shop_id END) AS total_deactivate 
FROM 
    test

GROUP BY 
    shipping_id 
ORDER BY 
    shipping_id
```